# Needs to ignore htaccess, when it contains wrong content

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I will explain, what I want to do.

We have an eshop, which generates htaccess file (server is Unix). Sometimes, it crashes during generating htaccess file, then whole site (frontend, admin, cron scripts => everything) is returning server error 500, due to not finished content in htaccess file.

And here is my question. I created script, which will regenerate htaccess file. But this script cant be anywhere in root (or subdirectories), because it will also return 500. Also subdomains are in root in subdirectory `/_sub`.

Is there any change to put it somewhere, where our customer will be able to execute it himself?

I cant use another domain; so I am asking, if there is any chance to ignore htaccess file, when it contants wrong content?

Thanks a lot.

**EDITED:**

I know, maybe one solution is here, but I think it will consume much more time, to code it all, but maybe not:

1. on another domain code script, which will connect through socket to ftp of eshop domain
2. it will delete htaccess file and recreate it to basic content
3. executing that cron, which will regenerate whole htaccess file

This should work, I think.

Comment: no. not possibble. if the .htaccess is bad, Apache **MUST** stop processing the request, because continuing onwards would generally be the WORST option. e.g. consider a .htaccess that normally contains `SetEnv NUKE_THE_WORLD false`. If the .htaccess is bad and request processing continues anyways, now there's no more planet.

Comment: @Marc B: thanks, I know, it will be "dangerous", just I was asking, if there is some option, but anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: Marc C2: because of your false security-based ideology lost unix the server market. I hope,sometimes you understand.

Comment: Yes, my edited question is working. :) 20 minutes of coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, maybe one solution is here, but I think it will consume much more time, to code it all, but maybe not:

1. on another domain code script, which will connect through socket to ftp of eshop domain
2. it will delete htaccess file and recreate it to basic content
3. executing that cron, which will regenerate whole htaccess file

This should work, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, how layman your customer are. Thw options: 1) you make this from cron 2) you put this in a cgi out.

But AFAIK the best were, if only a testing script from cron runs, and this reconstructed only the bad htaccess files.

Comment: I ment, customer = our client, who bought our eshop from us. There is only one htaccess file.

Comment: Then it is really simple. Be userfriendly and plugandplay. Don't say him anything just set up the crontest. It is what I did in your place.

Comment: But if it will return 500, how it will regenerate that htaccess file, when no script will be working on that domain? I can do crontest only from another domain, if that eshop is not returning 500.

Comment: command line php, have you ever heard from this? or if the site gives back 500, copy htaccess from backup, and do the reconstruction? be creative! :-)

Comment: Yes, as I have edited 30 minutes ago, I wrote the answer to my question. And it works.

Comment: I am very happy - if you too, please don't forget the upvote :-)